# jQuery Crashes on .live("keyup")

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

I have some code here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#querybox").live("keyup", function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13) {
       $("#querybox").blur();
    }
    else {
        search(document.getElementById('querybox').value);
    }

    /*if (document.getElementById('querybox').value == "") {
        $("center").removeHighlight();  
    }*/
});
});
```

that detects a keyUp and uses it to search something. The problem is: when the #querybox is backspaced to the point where it is empty, the entire page crashes and I get the "Awwww, Snap!" message from Google Chrome.

I am using jQuery v1.7.2

Thx a million!

**EDIT**

I should also point out that the *search()* function highlights text in the body (notice the commented section). I am using the [highlight](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) plugin...

---

Search Fn:

```
function search(query) {
    $("center").removeHighlight();
    $(".paragraph").highlight(query);
    $(".highlight").each(function (index) {
        $(this).attr("id", "tmpforgoToByClassScrollhighlight" + index);
    });
}
```

Comment: What is `search()`? And what have you found out from the Chrome developer tools?

Comment: Works fine for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/zmYpa/4/

Comment: @Walendas -- Can we see your code for `search(...)`?

Comment: 'search()' is a function I made which basically highlights the queried text: 'function search(query) { 
 $("center").removeHighlight(); 
 $(".paragraph").highlight(query);
 
 $(".highlight").each(function(index) {
  $(this).attr("id", "tmpforgoToByClassScrollhighlight"+index);
 });
}'

Comment: @Walendas ahhh put it in your question!

Comment: Not only is `live` depricated, you probably don't even need event delegation here at all.  Unless you are frequently removing and re-adding the element with the ID `querybox` to and from the DOM, simply binding an event handler once with `on` should work perfectly.

Comment: OK I will put the search() function in the question, but so far, I am using Neal's code (.on()). I will now try changing the plugin. (If that works, THX^1000000000 Neal!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`.on(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead:

```
$("#querybox").on("keyup", function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    var queryBox = this;
    if (code === 13) {   // PRESSED ENTER
       queryBox.blur();
    }
    else {
        search(queryBox.val());
    }
});
```

---

## After your update:

You might want to look better into how you do your search functiom.

Cache some of those jQuery elements so you do not keep selecting them over and over on each keyup.

Also, I am not going through all of the `.highlight` code, but there probably is a bug in there that **does not** allow for an empty string, and that is why the website is causing the browser to crash.

Comment: @Walendas, the guess about Highlight failing on an empty string is probably dead on: try running `$('.paragraph').highlight('')`.  I'm betting it will crash the page.

Comment: @apsillers Walendas is not here right now, please leave a message after the beep ***beeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeep***

Comment: BING BING BING WE HAVE A WINNER! It turns out (I'm not surprised) that the plugin that I was using was crap... I foun another one wich still needs some tweaking, but will sonn be up and running... :)

Comment: @Walendas see my update. I just realized that one of my lines was wrong. fixed that as well ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You should use [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//It will be a good advice to replace body with a parent element of #querybox
$("body").delegate("#querybox","keyup", function(e) {
 var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code == 13) {
    $("#querybox").blur();
  }
  else {
    search(document.getElementById('querybox').value);
  }

  /*if (document.getElementById('querybox').value == "") {
    $("center").removeHighlight();  
   }*/
 });
});
```